# ausearch: NOT operator in string match

Tags: audit, pattern-matching

When examining network activity logs from `audit`, I want to exclude a few programs I know, e.g. `firefox`.

```
ausearch -x firefox -i
```

brings up all firefox-related connections. But common NOT-operators seem to fail:

```
ausearch -x=!fire
ausearch -x \!fire
ausearch -x ^[fire]
```

How to **NOT** match a string in `ausearch`?

Note: this is not about defining the logging rules to exclude programs, but just filtering on the logs themselves.

Comment: Did you try `-x!=`?

Comment: @sebasth Yes, `unsupported option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround using `awk` (GNU version). Making use of `ausearch` separating blocks with `----`.

```
#!/bin/bash
ausearch -i | awk 'BEGIN { RS="----" } ; !/firefox/'
```